# Evento Document_KeyUp no funciona

Tags: vba, ms-word

Estoy intentando que cada vez que se presione la tecla `"` en mi documento word actual, se cambie el color del texto que voy a escribir. Pero el evento `key Up` no parece funciona, incluso le puse un `MsgBox` para ver si fue el código de la tecla y nada.

> Nota: Uso Office 2013

Este es mi codigo:

```VisualBasic
Private Sub Document_KeyPress(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Static Is_Str As Boolean
    
    If KeyCode = 34 Then
        ' Se presionó la tecla "
        If Is_Str Then
            ' End Str
            Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Else
            ' Init Str
            Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
        Is_Str = Not Is_Str
    End If
    MsgBox "Se ha presionado una tecla"
End Sub
```

Asi esta la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como quiero que se ejecute:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Nota: El documento esta habilitado para las macros y en opciones de seguridad permití que todas las macros se ejecuten.